# Shopping Cart rule to apply fixed discount on different product

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to add a shopping cart rule which gives the discount of 21 when there are specific five products in my cart. 
Eg: Five products with SKU S01, S02, S03, S04, S05, all having different product price. When added into cart total is 81 and Discount should be 21. The user should get these products in 60.
is this possible? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you apply the rule in this way, Please check the attached screen. 
There are five product at the different price and have applied a fixed amount discount. 
[image]